# Select multiple rows by max

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple table with a "versioning" scheme:

```
Version | PartKey1 | PartKey2 | Value
   1    |    0     |    0     | foo
   2    |    0     |    0     | bar
   1    |    1     |    0     | foobar
```

This table is medium (~100 000 lines for a full version). At the start it is loaded with a version 1 which contains a full snapshot, and over time incremental updates are added, but we want to preserve the old versions, thus they are added with an incremented "Version" number (2 here).

When reading the data, I want to be able to specify a maximum version, and I would like, if possible, to only retrieve the "rows" I am interested in.

For example: specifying 2 as the maximum version, I would like a query that retrieve only 2 rows in the table above:

```
Version | PartKey1 | PartKey2 | Value
   2    |    0     |    0     | bar
   1    |    1     |    0     | foobar
```

The row:

```
   1    |    0     |    0     | foo
```

is discarded because the version `2` *of this row* is more recent.

I was wondering if such a selection was possible / advisable in a SQL query. I can do the filtering on the application side, but obviously it means pulling in useless resources from the DB so if it's possible (and cheap on the DB side) I'd rather offload this work to the DB.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
SELECT v1.*
  FROM versioningscheme v1
  LEFT JOIN versioningscheme v2
    ON v2.partkey1 = v1.partkey1 AND v2.partkey2 = v1.partkey2
   AND v2.version > v1.version
 WHERE v2.version IS NULL
```

Left Join with NULL detection is very powerful and underused. Null values are returned when there is no match (and obviously, when you have the max row in v1, you can't get a row in v2 that satisfies the join condition).

Comment: I would strongly recommend testing this.  I don't have oracle access right now, but I would expect this type of self join to be expensive.

Comment: @Dems: Actually Oracle optimizer is smart enough to be very efficient at doing this. Rewriting queries to use such a left joins, even on large tables, has shown to boost performance up several times.

Comment: How would this compare with `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE keys=keys and version>version)`?  Both can be fullfilled with an anti-semi-join.  Would still compare this anti-semi-join approach against the GROUP BY and ROW_NUMBER() alternatives and explore the behaviours over a representative example data set.

Comment: @Dems: both versions should produce the same results but I have experienced that the LEFT JOIN is faster in our production cases. Maybe with other data it can be the other way.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.*
from MyTable t
inner join (
    select PartKey1, PartKey2, max(Version) as MaxVersion
    from MyTable
    where Version <= 2
    group by PartKey1, PartKey2
) tm on t.PartKey1 = tm.PartKey1 
    and t.PartKey2 = tm.PartKey2 
    and t.Version = tm.MaxVersion
```

Comment: Why the filter condition in the WHERE clause of the sub-query (CTE)?

Comment: @Jonathan: the OP said, *"When reading the data, I want to be able to specify a maximum version."* That `WHERE` clause is an example of how to do it.

Comment: Because the exact question involves the ability to specifiy a ceiling to the version number.  (The example given being 2).

Comment: +1: Fair enough -  missed that (not reading text carefully enough; just looking at the result set).

Answer (score 2):

This is common with time varying data (Where you choose to find the most recent value within a specific window of time), and is completely reasonable.

In your case, ROW_NUMBER() allows the data to be parsed just once, rather than multiple times.  With an appropriate INDEX such as `(PartKey1, PartKey2, Version)`, this should be exceptionally quick...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartKey1, PartKey2 ORDER BY Version DESC) AS reversed_version
  FROM
    MyTable
  WHERE
    Version <= <MaxVersionParamter>
)
  AS data
WHERE
  reversed_version = 1
```

Comment: I must admit I don't understand the query at all `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartKey1, PartKey2 ORDER BY Version DESC) AS reversed_version` is just unknown to me!

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Version DESC)` just creates a set of sequential numbers, ordered by version, in descending order.  Adding `PARTITION BY PartKey1, PartKey2` specifies that you get separate sequences of number for each unique combination of PartKey1, PartKey2.  There are also other windowing functions, such as commonly used RANK() and DENSE_RANK().  All are exceptionally quick when matched with appropriate indexes.  When used with the DESCending order, and the WHERE clause, you can esnure that the record oyu're interested in is always ROW_NUMBER() = 1.

Comment: this seems quite efficient, since the OrderBy naturally imposes a sort it looks like you would not perform any extraneous work. Do you know if it compares favorably with the various JOIN queries exposed ?

Comment: I don't *know* the answer on Oracle.  But on some systems the DESC is poorly optimised.  If it is effeciently optimised, it ends up being a seek, not a sort at all.  Even if it does have so sort the whole range (Version < 2) it still can out-perform alternatives.  You;d need to try it and see though.

Comment: thanks for your time, I definitely planned testing on realistic datasets anyway :)